# Ajax still executing even an error found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Good day programmers! I'am trying to submit a form then validate it using jquery with 2 ajax events. I am using ajax(timeconflict.php) for validating if there is conflict with the user's time input. but even tho it returns an error, the other ajax event is still executing(reserveroom.php). sorry for my grammar, here's my code

```
$('#submitreserve').click(function(){
var error=false;
var inputtimeerror = false;
var conflict = false;
var message="";
var to="";
var from="";
var fromH="";
var fromM="";
var toH="";
var toM="";
var now = new Date();

if($("#datetimepicker").val()=="" || $("#trtitle").val()=="" || $("#from").val()=="" || $("#to").val()=="")
{
  error = true;
  message ="Please Fill all required Fields!";
}
if($("#from").val()!="" && $("#to").val()!="")
  {
    from = $("#from").val(); // start time
    to = $("#to").val(); // end time
    fromH = from.substr(0,2); // get hour from start time
    fromM = from.substr(3,2); // get mins from start time

    toH = to.substr(0,2); // get hour from end time
    toM = to.substr(3,2); // get mins from end time

    var timeerror = false;
    var inputDate = $("#datetimepicker").val(); // date
    inputFrom = new Date(inputDate+" "+from); // time and start date
    inputTo = new Date(inputDate+" "+to); // time and end date

    if(fromH > toH)
    {
      timeerror=true;
    }

    if(fromH == toH && fromM >= toM)
    {
      timeerror=true;
    }

    if(to == from)
    {
      timeerror=true;
    }

    if(inputFrom <= now || inputTo <= now)
    {
      inputtimeerror = true;  
    }

    if(error == false && inputtimeerror == false)
    {
      $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url: 'timeconflict.php',
      data: { startTime : from,
      endTime : to,
      inputDate : inputDate,
      room : target },
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(e)
      {
        if (e.length == 0)
        {
          console.log("No value returned");
        }
        else
        {
          console.log(e[0]);
          console.log("Conflict time schedule!");
          conflict = true;
          error=true;
          alert("Conflict"); 
          return false;      
        }
      }
      });

    }

    if(inputtimeerror)
    {
      error=true;
      message = "Reservation time must be higher than time today!";
    }

    if(conflict)
    {
      error = true;
      message = "Conflict Time Schedule!";
    }

    if(timeerror)
    {
      message = "Invalid End Time!";
      error=true;
    }  

  }

if(error==true)
  {
    $("#error").text(message);
    return false;
  }

if(error==false)
  {
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'reserveroom.php',
    data: { trtitle : $("#trtitle").val(),
    from : $("#from").val(),
    to : $("#to").val(),
    datetimepicker : $("#datetimepicker").val(),
    ninjaday : $("#ninjaday").val(),
    ninjaroom : $("#ninjaroom").val() },
    dataType: 'json'
    });
  }
});

//timeconflict.php
<?php
include ('../conn.php');
// header("Content-Type: application/json");
$start_time = $_POST['startTime'];
$end_time = $_POST['endTime'];
$res_date = $_POST['inputDate'];
$res_room = $_POST['room'];

$sql = "SELECT * from tdc_reservation where ( ((`reserve_start` BETWEEN '".$start_time."' and '".$end_time."')";
$sql.= " or (`reserve_end` BETWEEN '".$start_time."'  and '".$end_time."' )) or";
$sql.= " (('".$start_time."' BETWEEN `reserve_start` and `reserve_end`) or ";
$sql.= " ('".$end_time."' BETWEEN `reserve_start` and `reserve_end`)) or ";
$sql.= " ((`reserve_start` = '".$start_time."' ) or (`reserve_end`='".$start_time."' ))";
$sql.= " or ((`reserve_start` = '".$end_time."') or (`reserve_end` = '".$end_time."')) )";
$sql.= " and reserve_date='".$res_date."' and reserve_room = '".$res_room."' LIMIT 1 ";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$stack = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $stack[] = $row;
      } 
 $json = json_encode($stack);


mysql_close();
echo $json;
?>
```

I really hope someone would help me, this error already ate 2 days of my life :(

Comment: call 2nd Ajax call after getting desired output from 1st Ajax call.

Comment: you mean put 2nd ajax to else statement? @(e.length==0)

Comment: yes, there inside you call your 2nd ajax call

Comment: I already did that before, but the problem is it would accept wrong time inputs. (e.g start time == end time or end time < start time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code, hope this will work

```
$('#submitreserve').click(function(){

var message="";
var to="";
var from="";
var fromH="";
var fromM="";
var toH="";
var toM="";
var now = new Date();

if($("#datetimepicker").val()=="" || $("#trtitle").val()=="" || $("#from").val()=="" || $("#to").val()=="")
{
  message ="Please Fill all required Fields!";
}else{


from = $("#from").val(); // start time
to = $("#to").val(); // end time
fromH = from.substr(0,2); // get hour from start time
fromM = from.substr(3,2); // get mins from start time

toH = to.substr(0,2); // get hour from end time
toM = to.substr(3,2); // get mins from end time


var inputDate = $("#datetimepicker").val(); // date
inputFrom = new Date(inputDate+" "+from); // time and start date
inputTo = new Date(inputDate+" "+to); // time and end date



if(fromH > toH || (fromH == toH && fromM >= toM) || to == from)
    {
      message = "Invalid End Time!";
    }
   else if(inputFrom <= now || inputTo <= now)
    {
      message = "Reservation time must be higher than time today!"; 
    }else{
      $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url: 'timeconflict.php',
      data: { startTime : from,
      endTime : to,
      inputDate : inputDate,
      room : target },
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(e)
      {
        if (e.length == 0)
        {
          console.log("No value returned");
          reserveRoom();
        }
        else
        {
          console.log(e[0]);
          console.log("Conflict time schedule!");
          alert("Conflict"); 
          return false;      
        }
      }
      });

    }

    }

    alert(message);

    });


function reserveRoom(){

$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'reserveroom.php',
    data: { trtitle : $("#trtitle").val(),
    from : $("#from").val(),
    to : $("#to").val(),
    datetimepicker : $("#datetimepicker").val(),
    ninjaday : $("#ninjaday").val(),
    ninjaroom : $("#ninjaroom").val() },
    dataType: 'json'
    });

}
```

Comment: If I do this, It would bypass all other validations that I made. like for example, reservation's end time must be greater than reservation's start time. buy anyway thanks for helping bro!

Comment: It won't bypass bro, I put all your conditions in single if condition.